# SymInitialize despite returning true is setting GetLastError to 2 what all this means?

Tags: c++, winapi

I use this compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev7.7z

code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <imagehlp.h>

int main() {
   HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
   if (GetLastError()) {
    printf("GetCurrentProcess failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
   }
   if (!SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE)) {
    printf("SymInitialize failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
  } else if (GetLastError()) {
    printf("SymInitialize returned true but failed nonetheless: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }
}
```

It returns: `SymInitialize returned true but failed nonetheless: 2`

error no 2 means "The system cannot find the file specified." What file, I can't put it in any context here. <s>I understand from documentation that if this function succeeds GetLastError *must* be zero.</s>

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that GetLastError *must* return zero if the function succeeded? As far as I can see, it only says that if the function failed, GetLastError will give you more information about the error. So most likely, the function just doesn't clear the error code if the function succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common that functions DON'T reset the error when successful. And it's entirely possible that "SymInitialize" internally calls some function that "Look for a file at dir1, look for a file at dir2, ...", and the error from "I couldn't find it in dir1" is 2. Now, you have to actually call SetLastError(0) to clear the error-code, and it may be an oversight or intentionally that the code in SymInitialize doesn't set that. You need to check the result of SymInitialize to tell if it was a success or not. If it's NOT a success, you look at the error code. But GetLastError() is just that - the last error that happened, not "did my last function succeed!"